# Mouse works only in some applications

Tags: unity, mouse

Recently my mouse has been buggy (actually one of the reasons I'm switching from Windows 8.1) (I say mouse, but I mean mice, I've tried several). It will work just fine, but when I try to click in the unity launcher to switch to a program such as Terminal it won't work.

If I then use alt+tab to switch to Terminal I cannot click in the still-exposed Firefox to switch to that, AND it will change the mouse cursor to show things in Firefox as if I was still focused on the window (show the hand when hovering over a link). But if I then try to type in Firefox, thinking Terminal is now just shown over all windows, it types in Terminal.

In Windows 8.1 I had a similar problem, I would run a program, but would only be able to use my mouse in it to click and right-click and everything for about 20 seconds before it would stop responding. NOTE: my mouse still moves around, I just can't click and sometimes it won't even register as hovering over something.

I'm currently on Ubuntu 14.04 and the other OS is Windows 8.1.

Any help is appreciated,
Ethan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was just an issue with the Razer mouse, once unplugged and uninstalled everything functioned correctly.